# How will I use my config to inject into my action mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I have a SITE_CONFIG that I load a yaml file from, it has:

site_name : "My site name"

Now in my mailer I am tring to do:

```
def registration

   mail ( :to => "...",
          :subject => "#{site_name}, please ... "

end
```

I can I use my SITE_CONFIG that was loaded from yaml to inject the value in the subject?

Answer (score 0):

```
:subject => "#{SITE_CONFIG["site_name"]}"
```

Assuming you used `YAML.load` to load `SITE_CONFIG`